# Web database solution for android?

Tags: android, database, google-app-engine

I' am supposed to write an application that lets you store data (contact informations) and sync that data to a server.

Now i am looking for an easy solution for the server side. -> an easy to set up web database that the app can communicate with, and a way to create a frontend, so that the customer can browse and maybe export the uploaded data.

Any suggestions? Could or should I use app engine for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think App Engine perfectly fits for that.
Since you're writing an Android app I guess that you'll write also the App Engine part in Java.

For storing data there is something called Datastore
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html

For the frontend there is the Google Web Toolkit short GWT
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/index.html

And because you're sending data from the Android app to the server you probably need to authenticate the user. Here is a great article about that. For the communication then just use POST request.
http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app

And use RPC for the browser client to App Engine communication
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html

However if you had googled that you would have found it out yourself...

Answer (score 2):

App Engine looks like a good choice for this. Use the low level data apis which will make your life easier.

Answer (score 2):

CouchDB perhaps is the solution, it can store data in mobile device, and sync data to server automatically.
Here is the site, http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/FrontPage
If local storage is not in the requirement, then an App Engine solution seems better.

Answer (score 1):

Easy and straight forward is relying on ruby on rails. But i suppose you don't want to switch languages. AppEngine combined with GWT (Google Web Toolkit) is an easy way of creating a frontend. You can also export the methods as Web-Servies. Another option is to work with "SpringRoo" (using REST) and a normal underlying database system such as mysql or, if you want to work with the real players: hibernate.

However, next time please specify your question more clearly, state your requirements.
What language, what means "easy to set up", what does the database need to do...